# Using React JS .12, how can the ownee know what ref it has been assigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem that I have been battling out all night. I recently upgraded to .12 and I'm running into problems with my child (ownee) component getting the ref it was given.

I understand that the ref attribute was removed from this.props but I cant seem to find it anywhere in my child component!

Pretty much

typeof this.ref === "undefined"

Any ideas would be great! I'm tired of fighting tonight. Signing off.

Comment: You really really really shouldn't need to do this ever.

Answer (score 1):

A few folks commented in various places saying "you shouldn't be doing this". This is rather unhelpful because it doesn't explain why, so I thought I'd take the time to do so.

I can't think of a good reason that an element would need to know it's own ref, that information is used for it's owner to communicate with it. If you really need to know it, as far as I know you can use this._currentElement.ref with the current version of React.

However. The reason _currentElement is prefixed with an underscore is because it is internal to React, it's an implementation detail. It is not whatsoever guaranteed by React's API and any update to React's library could break the fact that you can do this with the current version (assuming you update the version you are using). This also means you don't have any guarantee that this._currentElement.ref is actually the ref. It could be 50% of the time, and 50% of the time it could be garbage or undefined. You have no idea because it's an implementation detail and the implementation of the library isn't relevant to you, only the API is.

So I would strongly recommend that you reconsider why you need to rely on this piece of data and try to learn how you can restructure your React views in such a way that you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

Found it after getting a little sleep!

this._currentElement.ref

Im using it for backbone model integration!

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this

Comment: what @zackify said, here be bad mojo.